# Adjust Maui Grid Row height according to label with multiple rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I'm new to MAUI and I want to develop an app where the user has multiple input fields (dynamically added from an XML file). The problem is that the Grid cells seem to adjust fine when a label is just one row, but as soon as the text spills over to multiple rows the cell height isn't adjusted accordingly.

Check this example:

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label x:Name="c1r1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Some information that will span multiple rows. I'd like the row height to adjust accordingly." VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c2r1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="OK"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c3r1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Not OK at all"/>

            <Label x:Name="c1r2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Short text" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c2r2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="OK"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c3r2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="NOK"/>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This looks fine on a wide screen, like Windows Machine. However, on an Android Emulator with small screen, the long label text on column 0 row 0 wraps but only the first two rows are shown. Likewise the radio button on column 0 row 2 wraps, but is partially cut at the bottom.

I've tried different RowDefinition Height settings, like * and Auto, which didn't change anything.

I've also tried to wrap the controls in different types of layouts, but haven't found anything that does what I want.

What can I do to make the row height expand so that the whole text is visible??

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your Label Multiline:

Set LineBreakMode to set what happens when your Label's text has nowhere else to go on the specific line, usually multiline labels use CharacterWrap.

Set the Maxlines to an int value so it stops once you reach a maximum number of lines:

Other related properties can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label

```
<Label LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap" MaxLines="5"/>
```

Details on how maxlines works : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label#display-a-specific-number-of-lines

Comment: Hm. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work as specified. Regardless how I set LineBreakMode, MaxLines and LineHeight, a maximum of two lines is shown. Setting LineHeight > 1 does expand the grid row height, but still only two lines. The only way I found to see the full label text was to set the grid row height to 100, but that means each row will be 100 pixels which is ugly. Also, the radio button lacks these settings and when I set 100 pixels, the radio button moves but the text stays at the top, which is also ugly. Finally, there seems to be no difference between CharacterWrap and WordWrap.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful in your situation to use label's 'Loaded' event.

```
<ScrollView>
  <VerticalStackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="c1r1" Loaded="Label_Loaded" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Some information that will span multiple rows. I'd like the row height to adjust accordingly." VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="c2r1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="OK"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="c3r1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Not OK at all"/>

        <Label x:Name="c1r2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Short text" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="c2r2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="OK"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="c3r2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="NOK"/>
    </Grid>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the following handler

```
private void Label_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    var grid = label.Parent as Grid;
    var labelColumnWidthPart = grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value;
    var allColumnsWidthParts = grid.ColumnDefinitions.Select(definition => definition.Width).Sum(width => width.Value);
    var screenWidth = (DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density);
    var screenHeight = (DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density);
    var sizeRequest = label.Measure((screenWidth * labelColumnWidthPart) / allColumnsWidthParts, screenHeight);
    label.HeightRequest = sizeRequest.Request.Height;
}
```

Comment: Your handler works really well but only the first time the page is loaded. The next time it adds the height of the last item to the 2nd last item, and next time to the 3rd last item and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I created a demo and deployed to my android device(android 9), it works properly on my side. And I added a button to reset the text of label to a long text.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ScrollView> 
    <VerticalStackLayout
      >

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label x:Name="c1r1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Some information that will span multiple rows. I'd like the row height to adjust accordingly." VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c2r1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="OK" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c3r1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Not OK at all" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            <Label x:Name="c1r2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Short text" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c2r2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="OK" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="c3r2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="NOK" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button  Text="reset" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Method `Button_Clicked` ：

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
          {
        c1r1.Text = "Some information that will span multiple rows. I'd like the row height to adjust accordingly.abcddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddabcddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddabcdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
    }
```

**Note:**

> Also, the radio button lacks these settings and when I set 100 pixels,
> the radio button moves but the text stays at the top, which is also
> ugly.

For this, you can set the following property for each `RadioButton` :

```
 VerticalOptions="Center"
```